# How to access global enum in to web user control in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I have create global enum in my web site, but why I can't access in web user control.

I have create one static class where I define my all defaults, all variables can be accessible by page but can not in web user control.

Comment: Is the user control implemented in a separate project?

Comment: Andre Calil: No the User Control is in same project.

Comment: Anon ymous: No at server side

Comment: @chiragKhatsuriya: (1) Have you declared different namespaces? (2) What is it access modifier (`public`, `private`...) (3) You should comment using *@user* so we get notified of it.